# Disable onkeypress function

Tags: javascript

I am using onkeypress to work with a custom mask and I manually insert the character pressed. What happens though is that I find when i press 'a' two 'a' characters appear. one where I want it and one after the mask. Is there a way to disable the regular function of onkeypress so that it does not write a character to the textbox? This is for a custom mask that I am making for all texxtboxes of this type to have.

Comment: Just a little heads up: keep in mind that this won't be as simple as catching the key being pressed and appending it at the end of the text field. You'll also need to keep track of caret position. What if the user presses the home-key, or the arrow-keys, backspace, or delete, for instance? Or clicks in the middle of the textfield? Finding out whether caps lock was active (hence, if you should append `a` or `A`) is not trivial in javascript either. Some keys like `^` and `~` aren't outputted immediately, but affects the succeeding keystrokes.

Comment: @DavidHedlund: If you need to worry about caps lock then you're using the wrong event: only `keypress` tells you anything about the character typed, and gives you a character code that takes shift and caps lock into account.

Comment: @Tim: ah, that's right! Same goes for the other special chars I mentioned (no key press event is raised until the second keystroke). Caret position still matters, though. Not that it can't be done, I'm just saying, I've seen some really poor implementations where the author has not attended such details and it does an awful lot of harm to the user experience, usually only to achieve a trivial effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

modify your event function so it looks like this:

```
function onKeyPress(e){

    //All the code you already have

    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: AFAIK `return false;` equals `e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation();`, so that part is redundant.

Comment: @Viruzzo: Depends on how you're attaching the listener. However, `preventDefault()` will throw an error in all cases in IE < 9.

Answer (score 0):

You have to `return false` in your event handler.